# Using ng-repeat to get the column names of a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to generate a table using angularjs. The code is as follows

**Code:**

```
 <table>
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Column Name1</th>
             <th>Column Name2</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="item in Items">
             <th>{{Items[$index].Age}}</th>
             <th>{{Items[$index].School}}</th>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here what I want to do is that, when age and school data is generated in the table, they should go under a person's name and that name should appear in the column. How can I do this?

If I have an $scope array as follows;

```
$scope.Items = [{Name:Jhon,Age:23, School: 'some school'}....];
```

I want the colum name to be Jhon and Below that I want the other 2 data

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating through the array of Items where each object (in your case 'item') have a Age and School property for example:

```
var Items = [{Age:23, School: 'some school'}....];
```

this part is wrong:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in Items">
      <th>
         {{Items[$index].Age}}
      </th>
      <th>
         {{Items[$index].School}}
      </th>
</tbody>
```

it should be:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in Items">
      <th>
         {{item.Age}}
      </th>
      <th>
         {{item.School}}
      </th>
</tbody>
```

Comment: My problem is not with the repeating data in the columns. I want the names of the people who are having age and school as attributes in the columns. Let me edit the question so that it clear

Answer (score 0):

Look at the *snippet* below, that illustrates how to achieve the *Age* and *School* under the *Name*:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in Items">
        <td>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="2">{{item.Name}}</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><i>Age:</i> {{item.Age}}</td>
                <td align="center"><i>School:</i> {{item.School}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Watch the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/tr4zyr5w/).